# "Synchronise" loading of components in a page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic 1.3 mobile application in which I am using Angular 1.5. Each page is comprised of one or more Angular components and each one of these components may in turn contain other components, thus creating a component tree within the page.

The problem I have is that some of these components might require data from the server, which are loaded in the component's $onInit function. Since this data is retrieved asynchronously (and there might be delays) the result is for the components to appear one after the other in the page (depending on when each one manages to initialise) which doesn't make for a very "native" mobile experience. What I would like to do is find a way to know when all components have finished loading so that I can display the page only after it is really ready (all components are fully rendered).

My original idea was to "register" each component with a service when its controller initialises and then notify the service that the component is ready once the data is loaded. The service can then be responsible for showing the page when all components are ready. My problem with doing this is that components seem to initialise sequentially (ie. component1's controller initialises and then $onInit executes, then component2's controller initialises and $onInit executes, etc.) which means that my service can't really know how many components it is waiting for. Not only that, but also a component's children controllers initialise and their $onInit methods execute after the parent component has finished initialising, which means that the component also can't keep track of whether its children have initialised or not.

An alternative would be to hard-code the number of components somewhere in the page and pass it to the service through the page controller so that it knows how many components to wait for without the components needing to register themselves, but ideally I would like something a bit more maintainable (ie. something that doesn't require me to keep track of components and keep this number up to date myself).

Can anyone think of any other way I can keep track of when my page is ready using either Angular or Ionic? Ideally it would be something that can also be ported to Angular2 / Ionic2 since I expect the app to get upgraded at some point, but any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use resolve in ui.router or ngRoute:

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider)     { 
    $stateProvider.state('mainstate', {
         url: 'your-url'
         ,templateUrl: 'yout_template.html'
         ,controller: 'YourController'
         ,resolve: {
              yourFirstData: ['serviceDeps', function(serviceDeps){ 
                    return serviceDeps.getFirstData();
              }]
              ,yourSecondData: ['serviceDeps', 'yourFistData', function(serviceDeps, yourSecondData){ 
                    return serviceDeps.getSecondData(yourFirstData); 
              }
         }
    }
}]);
```

The resolve will get the data and resolve promises before loading controller.

This is an ideia.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however in my case this will not work because the way the app is built the components are added to the page at build time (through some configuration logic) and therefore there is no way of knowing exactly which components will be put in each page in order to account for their data in the resolve of UI router.